# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation(SQLServer spatial 2008 R2)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, gis

I am getting the following error when i try to read the geography data from SQLServer spatial 2008 R2 as i am trying to display geography features on aspx page using Dot Spatiakl.Please do the needful to solve this issue.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Resources.ResourceReader.DeserializeObject(Int32 typeIndex)
       at System.Resources.ResourceReader._LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
       at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
       at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObject(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
       at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean isString)
       at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase)
       at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)
       at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture)


       at DotSpatial.Symbology.SymbologyImages.get_select() in D:\Arun Working\Dot Spatial\dotspatial-66654\DotSpatial.Symbology\SymbologyImages.Designer.cs:line 121
       at DotSpatial.Symbology.FeatureLayer.Configure(IFeatureSet featureSet) in D:\Arun Working\Dot Spatial\dotspatial-66654\DotSpatial.Symbology\FeatureLayer.cs:line 249
       at DotSpatial.Symbology.FeatureLayer..ctor(IFeatureSet featureSet) in D:\Arun Working\Dot Spatial\dotspatial-66654\DotSpatial.Symbology\FeatureLayer.cs:line 148
       at DotSpatial.Symbology.PolygonLayer..ctor(IFeatureSet inFeatureSet) in D:\Arun Working\Dot Spatial\dotspatial-66654\DotSpatial.Symbology\PolygonLayer.cs:line 44
       at DotSpatial.Controls.MapPolygonLayer..ctor(IFeatureSet inFeatureSet) in D:\Arun Working\Dot Spatial\dotspatial-66654\DotSpatial.Controls\MapPolygonLayer.cs:line 84
       at DotSpatial.Controls.MapLayerCollection.Add(IFeatureSet featureSet) in D:\Arun Working\Dot Spatial\dotspatial-66654\DotSpatial.Controls\MapLayerCollection.cs:line 205
       at DotSpatial.WebControls.GDIMap.AddLayer1(FeatureSet sqlpoly) in D:\Arun Working\Dot Spatial\dotspatial-66654\DotSpatial.WebControls\GDIMap.cs:line 164
       at DotSpatial.WebControls.WebMap.AddLayer1(FeatureSet sqlpoly) in D:\Arun Working\Dot Spatial\dotspatial-66654\DotSpatial.WebControls\WebMap.cs:line 399
       at Element_DotSpatial.MapReport.DrawTheGeography(SqlGeography geog, String myLayerName, String myItemLegend, Color fillColour, Color outlineColour, Double lineWidth, Boolean zoomTo) in D:\Arun Working\Projects\Element_DotSpatial\Element_DotSpatial\MapReport.aspx.cs:line 216
       at Element_DotSpatial.MapReport.CreateMap() in D:\Arun Working\Projects\Element_DotSpatial\Element_DotSpatial\MapReport.aspx.cs:line 56
       at Element_DotSpatial.MapReport.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Arun Working\Projects\Element_DotSpatial\Element_DotSpatial\MapReport.aspx.cs:line 29
       at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
       Message=The operation completed successfully
       Source=System.Drawing
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       NativeErrorCode=0
       StackTrace:
            at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height)
            at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       InnerException:
```

Regards
Arun Mohan